# What does this phishing email achieve?

Tags: phishing

The email is formatted as an email from Google notifying me that I need to respond to an intrusion attempt on my account. There are no other links other than these `href mailto` links ("Oui Moi!" and "pas moi!") to have me send "pas moi" (meaning "not me") to 39 email addresses.

My Google ID (blurred) appears several times in the recipients list (blurred but framed in red). I understand this allows them to exfiltrate that piece of information (my ID).

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Both buttons do the same thing?

Comment: If both buttons do the same thing, then they want to harvest email addresses of people who are prime to respond to fake Google emails. The real phishing comes later.

Comment: ok that makes sense. I'll respond..

Comment: While the duplicate is not a perfect duplicate, it's the same concept. Your example aoutmates the email response.

Comment: I have the answer to this particular spam: what happens next, is that the email client (gmail in my case) considers all of the previous senders as NOT SPAM(MMERS), hence, every subsequent email received from those addresses is not flagged as spam, so it goes directly to the inbox, bypassing any spam filter. I didn't find this detail in the other questions / answers.